# Error while installing the library bls-lib in python3

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10

I have tried to install the `bls-lib` library but this error kept showing, can anyone help me what's wrong with it? I even tried to install the `petlib` library because I thought that it will solve the problem but I got an almost simmilar error.

```
(venv) C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\Testing\venv>pip install bls-lib
Collecting bls-lib
  Using cached bls_lib-1.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Collecting bplib
  Using cached bplib-0.0.6.tar.gz (40 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\admin\pycharmprojects\testing\venv\scripts\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Lo
cal\\Temp\\pip-install-bys_0pq0\\bplib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-bys_0pq0\\bplib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tok
enize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-ba
se 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-b9zc7inm'
         cwd: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-bys_0pq0\bplib\
    Complete output (63 lines):
        ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
         command: 'c:\users\admin\pycharmprojects\testing\venv\scripts\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData
\\Local\\Temp\\pip-wheel-p1rs96jl\\petlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-wheel-p1rs96jl\\petlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(t
okenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-
base 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-iyyhus4_'
             cwd: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-p1rs96jl\petlib\
        Complete output (27 lines):
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
          File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-p1rs96jl\petlib\setup.py", line 7, in <module>
            setup(name='petlib',
          File "c:\users\admin\pycharmprojects\testing\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 153, in setup
            return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
          File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\distutils\core.py", line 108, in setup
            _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
          File "c:\users\admin\pycharmprojects\testing\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 423, in __init__
            _Distribution.__init__(self, {
          File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 292, in __init__
            self.finalize_options()
          File "c:\users\admin\pycharmprojects\testing\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 695, in finalize_options
            ep(self)
          File "c:\users\admin\pycharmprojects\testing\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 702, in _finalize_setup_keywords
            ep.load()(self, ep.name, value)
          File "c:\users\admin\pycharmprojects\testing\venv\lib\site-packages\cffi\setuptools_ext.py", line 219, in cffi_modules
            add_cffi_module(dist, cffi_module)
          File "c:\users\admin\pycharmprojects\testing\venv\lib\site-packages\cffi\setuptools_ext.py", line 49, in add_cffi_module
            execfile(build_file_name, mod_vars)
          File "c:\users\admin\pycharmprojects\testing\venv\lib\site-packages\cffi\setuptools_ext.py", line 25, in execfile
            exec(code, glob, glob)
          File "petlib/compile.py", line 34, in <module>
            openssl_conf = os.environ["OPENSSL_CONF"]
          File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\os.py", line 679, in __getitem__
            raise KeyError(key) from None
        KeyError: 'OPENSSL_CONF'
        ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\admin\pycharmprojects\testing\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py", line 126, in fetch_build_egg
        subprocess.check_call(cmd)
      File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 373, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['c:\\users\\admin\\pycharmprojects\\testing\\venv\\scripts\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wh
eel', '--no-deps', '-w', 'C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpu5quqolr', '--quiet', 'petlib>=0.0.45']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    
    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-bys_0pq0\bplib\setup.py", line 7, in <module>
        setup(name='bplib',
      File "c:\users\admin\pycharmprojects\testing\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 152, in setup
        _install_setup_requires(attrs)
      File "c:\users\admin\pycharmprojects\testing\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 147, in _install_setup_requires
        dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
      File "c:\users\admin\pycharmprojects\testing\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 673, in fetch_build_eggs
        resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
      File "c:\users\admin\pycharmprojects\testing\venv\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 764, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(
      File "c:\users\admin\pycharmprojects\testing\venv\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1049, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "c:\users\admin\pycharmprojects\testing\venv\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1061, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "c:\users\admin\pycharmprojects\testing\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 732, in fetch_build_egg
        return fetch_build_egg(self, req)
      File "c:\users\admin\pycharmprojects\testing\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py", line 128, in fetch_build_egg
        raise DistutilsError(str(e)) from e
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Command '['c:\\users\\admin\\pycharmprojects\\testing\\venv\\scripts\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', '
wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', 'C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpu5quqolr', '--quiet', 'petlib>=0.0.45']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

This is the error of installing the `petlib` library:

```
(venv) C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\Testing>pip install petlib
Collecting petlib
  Using cached petlib-0.0.45.tar.gz (245 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\admin\pycharmprojects\testing\venv\scripts\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Lo
cal\\Temp\\pip-install-yp8f_epx\\petlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-yp8f_epx\\petlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(t
okenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-
base 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-gyl6jkzc'
         cwd: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yp8f_epx\petlib\
    Complete output (27 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yp8f_epx\petlib\setup.py", line 7, in <module>
        setup(name='petlib',
      File "c:\users\admin\pycharmprojects\testing\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 153, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\distutils\core.py", line 108, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "c:\users\admin\pycharmprojects\testing\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 423, in __init__
        _Distribution.__init__(self, {
      File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 292, in __init__
        self.finalize_options()
      File "c:\users\admin\pycharmprojects\testing\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 695, in finalize_options
        ep(self)
      File "c:\users\admin\pycharmprojects\testing\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 702, in _finalize_setup_keywords
        ep.load()(self, ep.name, value)
      File "c:\users\admin\pycharmprojects\testing\venv\lib\site-packages\cffi\setuptools_ext.py", line 219, in cffi_modules
        add_cffi_module(dist, cffi_module)
      File "c:\users\admin\pycharmprojects\testing\venv\lib\site-packages\cffi\setuptools_ext.py", line 49, in add_cffi_module
        execfile(build_file_name, mod_vars)
      File "c:\users\admin\pycharmprojects\testing\venv\lib\site-packages\cffi\setuptools_ext.py", line 25, in execfile
        exec(code, glob, glob)
      File "petlib/compile.py", line 34, in <module>
        openssl_conf = os.environ["OPENSSL_CONF"]
      File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\os.py", line 679, in __getitem__
        raise KeyError(key) from None
    KeyError: 'OPENSSL_CONF'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Have you read the instructions as posted https://github.com/gdanezis/petlib#pre-requisites?

Comment: Yes I did. But when I tried the `vcvarsx86_amd64.bat` command it didn't work, it kept telling me that it didn't recognize the command

Comment: @ewong Just to make sure, in which path I have to run the `vcvarsx86_amd64.bat` to configure the path variables of Microsoft VS?